# Android spinner widget looks weird on Galaxy S GT-I9000

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I have this spinner:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/language_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

It looks like it should on all the devices I had been testing. I recently received an error report saying that on the Galaxy S GT-I9000 it looks weird. I borrowed a Galaxy S GT-I9000 and confirmed, the downward arrow is displayed on top of the text instead being displayed to the right of the text.

Here is a screenshot from the Galaxy S GT-I9000 (with the weird spinner) and a screenshot from the HTC One S (with the normal spinner).

[image: Weird]

[image: Normal]

Changing the android:gravity doesn't help. Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

try giving it a fixed length:

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="100dp"
```

and see how it goes.